# Babel Package Installation Problems

Tags: miktex, babel, texniccenter

At an earlier time **babel** package is functioning normally. But now, when compiling **tex** files, **MikTeX** asked to install the **babel** package, even after it's installed *again* and *again*.

```
The required file
tex\latex\babel-english\english.ldf
is missing. It is a part of the following package:
babel-english
```

I use **TeXnicCenter** editor.

Comment: Synchronize your databases: Package manager (admin *and* user version), menu repositories. Check for updates (again with user and admin manager). Then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Now babel language definition files are independent of the main babel installation (it's a change between version 3.8 and version 3.9). So probably `babel-english` is not installed, and you have to install it with MiKTeX Package Manager.

[image]